# Glossaries with Pandoc (+ LaTeX)

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to create a glossary using Pandoc with Markdown in, PDF (/LaTeX) out. I've followed the documentation [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary) which uses the `glossaries` library. Everything *seems* to be working, **except** actually printing out the glossary! And yes, I have `\printglossaries` in my template.

The documentation there mentions

> File processing must now include a call to `makeglossaries` followed by at least one further invocation of `latex` or `pdflatex`.

which...I haven't done, because I don't know how. Is there a canonical or easy way to run `latex` or `pdflatex` again, as it says, using pandoc?

---

What I've done so far:

1. Made a copy of the default template (using `pandoc -D latex`) and added this right after `$body$`, before the bibliography stuff:

   ```
   $if(glossary)$
   \printglossaries
   $endif$
   ```
2. Updated my main doc YAML metadata to include `glossary: true`.
3. My `header-includes` section looks like this:

   ```
   header-includes:
       - \usepackage{glossaries}
       - \makeglossaries
       - \newglossaryentry{foo}{name=bar, description={baz}}
   ```
4. In the document I have `\gls{foo}` in an arbitrary location near the beginning, which *does* get hyperlinked, just...to nowhere.
5. Compile using `pandoc --standalone --template=aui.latex my_document.md -o my_document.pdf`.

I've also tried without the conditional `glossary` variable stuff, just in case that's what was breaking things, but there's no change.

Comment: could you show some data? an excerpt of your glossary in pandoc markdown, the lines you added to the standard pandoc template, and the commands you currently use to compile it.

Comment: you can always `pandoc -o out.tex && pdflatex out.tex && pdflatex out.tex`

Comment: @mb21 Ah, I didn't realize you had to call `pdflatex out.tex` *twice*. @scoa sure, let me update the question.

Answer (score 7):

If you use option 1 from section 4 of the [glossaries beginners guide](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) to show your glossary, you will not need multiple invocations of `pdflatex`. It should compile ok with a single run.

Also if you want to use a less latexy syntax in your markdown files you can use the filter I wrote: [pandoc-gls](https://github.com/tomncooper/pandoc-gls). The pandoc-gls repo also has an example meta section setup for the option 1 mentioned above.